# adding a parameter in get request generated by onclick

Tags: php, html

```
 echo '< button onclick="run(\'' . $A . '\', \'B\')">Button< /button >';
```

this sends a GET request with `id=valueOf($A)` and `type = B`

How can I add another parameter to it
lets say i want a get request with `id1=valueOf($A1), id2 = valueOf($A2)` and `type = B`

please ignore the spaces. Had to add those as editor of stackoverflow was giving some issues

Comment: What you are exactly looking for? I tried st. in my answer below, but i don´t know if it exactly what you need. It only adds 3rd param to your function `run`, but it has to be no problem when you was able to create func with two params...

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this?

```
echo '<button onclick="run(\'' . $A . '\', \'' . $B . '\' \'B\')">Button</button>';
```

Comment: no that does not works
now when i click on the button, it does nothing

Comment: In HTML is the only way to add another parameter. You have to process that in JS/PHP, of course. Then you have to declate `$B`, of course.